# Replace text in a list with formatted text in another list

Tags: python

I am attempting to replace text in a list with text from another list. Below, `lst_a` has the string length I need for another script, but none of the formatting from `lst_b`. I want to give `lst_a` the correct spelling, capitalization, and punctuation from `lst_b`.

**For example:**

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']
```

I'm not 100% sure the best way to approach this problem.

I have tried breaking `lst_a` into a smaller `sub_lst_a` and taking the difference from each list, but I'm not sure what to do when entire items exist in one list and not the other (e.g. 'it' and 'is' rather than 'it's').

Regardless, any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution attempt below:**

I thought it may be worth trying to break `lst_a` into a list just of words. Then I thought to enumerate each item, so that I could more easily identify it's counter part in `lst_b`. From there I wanted to take the difference of the two lists, and replace the values in `lst_a_diff` with `lst_b_diff`. I had to sort the lists because my diff script wasn't consistently ordering the outputs.

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']

# splitting lst_a into a smaller sub_lst_a
def convert(lst_a):
    return ([i for item in lst_a for i in item.split()])   
sub_lst_a = convert(lst_a)

# getting the position values of sub_lst_a and lst_b
lst_a_pos = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(sub_lst_a)]
lst_b_pos = [f"{i}, {v}" for i, v in enumerate(lst_b)]

# finding the difference between the two lists
def Diff(lst_a_pos, lst_b_pos):
    return list(set(lst_a_pos) - set(lst_b_pos))

lst_a_diff = Diff(lst_a_pos, lst_b_pos)
lst_b_diff = Diff(lst_b_pos, lst_a_pos)

# sorting lst_a_diff and lst_b_diff by the original position of each item
lst_a_diff_sorted = sorted(lst_a_diff, key = lambda x: int(x.split(', ')[0]))
lst_b_diff_sorted = sorted(lst_b_diff, key = lambda x: int(x.split(', ')[0]))

print(lst_a_diff_sorted)
print(lst_b_diff_sorted)
```

**Desired Results:**

```
final_lst_a = ['It\'s an', 'example of', 'an English simple sentence.']
```

Comment: Why does `lst_a` have more than just individual words in it?

Comment: Can you also include desired result? I understand what you are *trying* to do, but details matter: do you want to create a new list? Replace in existing list? Whatever your expected result will be helpful.

Comment: It is coming from an SRT file, and each string of words is what appears during a specific duration of time.

Comment: For sure, I just entered them above at the end of the post!

Comment: `lst_a` only contains lowercase letters?

Comment: Yes, and no punctuation.

Comment: "no punctuation" means also "no apostrophe"?

Comment: Yes, also no apostrophe.

Comment: Also, where does `lst_b` come from?

Comment: `lst_b` is coming from a JSON file. Basically the confidence interval for each word and the word itself are the contents.

Comment: Yes `lst_b` contains all of the desired words of `lst_a`. However, with word contractions `lst_b` is somewhat smaller in length, and I need the string length of each item in `lst_a` because the align with time stamps.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but the example sentence is odd; normally the adjectives would be swapped, "a simple English sentence".

Answer (score 1):

## Solution walkthrough

Assuming as you say that the two lists are essentially always in order, to properly align the indexes in both, words with apostrophe should really count for two.

One way to do that is for example to expand the words by adding an empty element:

```
# Fill in blanks for words that have apostrophe: they should count as 2
lst_c = []
for item in lst_b:
  lst_c.append(item)
  if item.find("'") != -1:
    lst_c.append('')
print(lst_c)

>> ["It's", '', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']
```

Now it is a matter of expanding `lst_a` on a word-by-word basis, and then group them back as in the original lists. Essentially, we align the lists like this:

```
['it',  'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'english', 'simple', 'sentence']
["It's", '',  'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']
```

then we create `new_item` slices like these:

```
["It's", "", "an"]
["example of"]
["an English simple sentence"]
```

The code looks like this:

```
# Makes a map of list index and length to extract
final = []
ptr = 0
for item in lst_a:
  # take each item in lst_a and count how many words it has
  count = len(item.split())

  # then use ptr and count to correctly map a slice off lst_c
  new_item = lst_c[ptr:ptr+count]

  # get rid of empty strings now
  new_item = filter(len, new_item)

  # print('new[{}:{}]={}'.format(ptr,count,new_item))

  # join the words by single space and append to final list      
  final.append(' '.join(new_item))

  # advance the ptr
  ptr += count

  >> ["It's an", 'example of', 'an English simple sentence.']
```

## Complete code solution

This seems to handle other cases well enough. The complete code would be something like:

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']

# This is another example that seems to work
# lst_a = ['tomorrow I will', 'go to the movies']
# lst_b = ['Tomorrow', 'I\'ll', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'movies.']

# Fill in blanks for words that have apostrophe: they should count as 2
lst_c = []
for item in lst_b:
  lst_c.append(item)
  if item.find("'") != -1:
    lst_c.append('')

print(lst_c)

# Makes a map of list index and length to extract
final = []
ptr = 0
for item in lst_a:
  count = len(item.split())
  # print(ptr, count, item)
  new_item = lst_c[ptr:ptr+count]
  # get rid of empty strings now
  new_item = filter(len, new_item)
  # print('new[{}:{}]={}'.format(ptr,count,new_item))
  ptr += count
  final.append(' '.join(new_item))

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']

for word in lst_b:
    # If a word is capitalized, look for it in lst_a and capitalize it
    if word[0].upper() == word[0]:
        for idx, phrase in enumerate(lst_a):
            if word.lower() in phrase:
                lst_a[idx] = phrase.replace(word.lower(), word)

    if "'" in word:
    # if a word has an apostrophe, look for it in lst_a and change it
    # Note here you can include other patterns like " are", 
    # or maybe just restrict it to "it is", etc.
        for idx, phrase in enumerate(lst_a):
            if " is" in phrase:
                lst_a[idx] = phrase.replace(" is", "'s")
                break

print(lst_a)
```

Comment: Your code prints `["it's an", 'example of', 'an English simple sentence']`. It should be `["It's an", 'example of', 'an English simple sentence.']`.

Comment: Hahah fair point. I'll leave it for him for figure that part out

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```py
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence']
lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'English', 'simple', 'sentence.']

lst_a_split = []
end_indices_in_lst_a_split = []

# Construct "lst_a_split" and "end_indices_in_lst_a_split".
# "lst_a_split" is supposed to be ['it', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'english', 'simple', 'sentence'].
# "end_indices_in_lst_a_split" is supposed to be [3, 5, 9].
end = 0
for s in lst_a:
    s_split = s.split()
    end += len(s_split)
    end_indices_in_lst_a_split.append(end)
    for word in s_split:
        lst_a_split.append(word)

# Construct "d" which contains
# index of every word in "lst_b" which does not include '\'' as value
# and the corresponding index of the word in "lst_a_split" as key.
# "d" is supposed to be {2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 6, 8: 7}.
d = {}
start = 0
for index_in_lst_b, word in enumerate(lst_b):
    if '\'' in word:
        continue
    word = word.lower().strip('.').strip(',').strip('"')  # you can add other strip()'s as you want
    index_in_lst_a_split = lst_a_split.index(word, start)
    start = index_in_lst_a_split + 1
    d[index_in_lst_a_split] = index_in_lst_b

# Construct "final_lst_a".
final_lst_a = []
start_index_in_lst_b = 0
for i, end in enumerate(end_indices_in_lst_a_split):
    if end - 1 in d:
        end_index_in_lst_b = d[end - 1] + 1
        final_lst_a.append(' '.join(lst_b[start_index_in_lst_b:end_index_in_lst_b]))
        start_index_in_lst_b = end_index_in_lst_b
    elif end in d:
        end_index_in_lst_b = d[end]
        final_lst_a.append(' '.join(lst_b[start_index_in_lst_b:end_index_in_lst_b]))
        start_index_in_lst_b = end_index_in_lst_b
    else:
        # It prints the following message if it fails to construct "final_lst_a" successfully.
        # It would happen if words in "lst_b" on both sides at a boundary contain '\'', which seem to be unlikely.
        print(f'Failed to find corresponding words in "lst_b" for the string "{lst_a[i]}".')
        break

print(final_lst_a)
```

which prints

```
["It's an", 'example of', 'an English simple sentence.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have a few responses to review. Here's something that should help you expand the implementation.

In addition to `lst_a` and `lst_b`, what if you could give all the lookup items like `'It's'`, `'I'll'`, `'don't'` and you could outline what it should represent, then the below could would take care of that lookup as well.

```
#original lst_a. This list does not have the punctuation marks
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence', 'if time permits', 'I will learn','this weekend', 'but do not', 'count on me']

#desired output with correct spelling, capitalization, and punctuation
#but includes \' that need to be replaced

lst_b = ['It\'s', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'english', 'simple', 'sentence.', 'If', 'time', 'permits,','I\'ll', 'learn','this','weekend', 'but', 'don\'t','count', 'on', 'me']

#lookup list to replace the contractions
ch = {'It\'s':['It','is'],'I\'ll':['I','will'], 'don\'t':['do','not']}

#final list will be stored into lst_c
lst_c = []

#enumerate through lst_b to replace all words that are contractions
for i,v in enumerate(lst_b):

    #for this example, i am considering that all contractions are 2 part words
    for j,k in ch.items():

        if v == j:       #here you are checking for contractions

            lst_b[i] = k[0] #for each contraction, you are replacing the first part
            lst_b.insert(i+1,k[1]) #and inserting the second part


#now stitch the words together based on length of each word in lst_b
c = 0
for i in lst_a:
    j = i.count(' ') #find out number of words to stitch together
    #stitch together only the number of size of words in lst_a
    lst_c.append(' '.join([lst_b[k] for k in range (c, c+j+1)]))
    c += j+1

#finally, I am printing lst_a, lst_b, and lst_c. The final result is in lst_c
print (lst_a, lst_b, lst_c, sep = '\n')
```

**Output for this is as shown below:**

```
lst_a = ['it is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence', 'if time permits', 'I will learn', 'this weekend', 'but do not', 'count on me']
lst_b = ['It', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'an', 'english', 'simple', 'sentence.', 'If', 'time', 'permits,', 'I', 'will', 'learn', 'this', 'weekend', 'but', 'do', 'not', 'count', 'on', 'me']
lst_c = ['It is an', 'example of', 'an english simple sentence.', 'If time permits,', 'I will learn', 'this weekend', 'but do not', 'count on me']
```

Comment: @teddygraham, looks like this addressed your problem statement. Let me know if this needs further refinement.